# How can I download data about a single "thing" from multiple tables without massive duplication?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several tables containing data about one logical "thing", e.g. a post. My application wants to see all the data about several posts, e.g. comments and reactions, that live in separate tables.

How can I best combine the data from several tables for presentation to my application? I'm wary of two problems:

- Download time
- Ease of parsing

Apologies if this is covered elsewhere - I found it hard to search for

A concrete example on SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/01616/3. Summarised here:

```
Tables:

posts (
  id int,
  content text
)

comments (
  id int,
  post_id int,
  content text
)

reactions (
  post_id int,
  emoji char,
  count int
)
```

I've thought of a few options:

1. I could get all the data I need with a simple join:

```sql
select * from 
posts as p 
inner join comments as c on c.post_id = p.id
inner join reactions as r on r.post_id = p.id;
```

but the number of rows returned per post will be `(number of reactions) x (number of comments)` which could quickly get out of hand. The content of the post is also included in every row, if it's long then the amount of data being downloaded could explode. Let alone if I want a 4th table later.

The application would also need to know which columns referred to the post, which to reactions and which to comments. Not as big a problem but could easily become messy.

2. The application could run multiple queries:

- Get posts
- For each post, get comments and get reactions

But that involves at least 2 round trips, more if another layer of data was added such as reactions to comments.

3. The application could select all the relevant data from the individual tables then "join" them itself. This would work in 1 trip and with minimal data download but feels like I'm throwing away the benefit of a relational database by building the relations application-side.
4. The query could return one row per post by crushing the comments and reactions into a single column each (as an array of JSON maybe?). This again feels very wrong and messy, I'm not even sure if it's possible.

PS - I'm using Postgres but don't imagine that matters

**Edit:**
To give a bit more clarity on the exact data I want in this example, say my database looks like:

Posts

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A post |
| 2 | A second post |
| 3 | A third post |

Comments

| id | post_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Great post |
| 2 | 1 | Yeah it is |
| 3 | 2 | Lol |
| 4 | 3 | Hello there |

Reactions

| post_id | emoji | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 12 |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 10 |

If the app wants to show posts 1 and 2, including their comments and reactions, then  it needs data from several tables. Here's the minimal data it would need in JSON format for ease:

```json
{
  posts: [
    {
      content: "A post",
      comments: [
        {content: "Great post"},
        {content: "Yeah it is"},
      ],
      reactions: [
        {emoji: "", count: 12},
        {emoji: "", count: 1},
      ],
    },
    {
      content: "A second post",
      comments: [
        {content: "lol"},
      ],
      reactions: [
        {emoji: "", count: 10},
      ],
    } 
  ]
}
```

My question is - how to efficiently get that data?

Comment: Instead of select *, can you not just select post.id and then count(*) or group by to get what you want? It sounds like you want *something* from reactions and comments, but your post doesn't say what. If all you want is count, then a group by clause will limit the result to only be 1 row per post.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll clarify.

In this example what I want is for the application to be able to load, for a subset of posts:
- The post content
- The content of any comments linked to the post
- The reactions to that post, i.e. the emoji and count entries of any reactions linked to the post